# How to know if an event lasts multiple months

Tags: ios, swift

**App Overview**

I'm building an iOS app in Swift that shows a list of events. The data that I have for the events shows the name of the event, the start date (day, month, year), and the end date (day, month, year).

When the data is pulled from Firebase, I look at the start and end months and show the event for the appropriate month in a table view. The data is shown by month, so a user looking at May only sees May events and has to choose a different month to see events from that month.

**Problem**

Some events stretch for several months. For example, if an event begins in July and ends in September, my current implementation won't show the events during August.

**Possible Solutions**

I'm looking for an elegant way to programmatically check for this case and make sure it's shown in the correct month rather than manually manipulating the data to state the months in between.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Here is the solution that I'm considering:

1. Add a Bool data point saying if the event stretches several months or not. When events for a specific month are shown, check through all of these events to see if the month selected is greater than the start month of the event and less than the end month of the event.

This breaks down if the event stretches from one year into the next. I would need to add additional logic to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are simply comparing the displayed month to the event's start month and the event's end month.

Without any specifics your basic logic to determine whether to show an event in a displayed month is to see if the displayed month is greater to or equal to the event start month and less than or equal to the even end month.

In pseudo code that would essentially be:

```
if displayMonth >= event.startMonth && displayMonth <= event.endMonth {
    // show event
}
```

Of course this needs to account for the year as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to check month you also need to check year. For example:

```
// Check start date
if (displayYear == event.startYear && displayMonth >= event.startMonth) || displayYear > event.startYear {
    // Check end date
    if (displayYear == event.endYear && displayMonth <= event.endMonth) || displayYear < event.endYear {
        // show event
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information or description of this code

Answer (score -1):

comparing dates will work for you.

compare current date with starting date and ending date.

current date should be greater than starting date and less than ending date.

Here is code snippests for Date comparision

if currentDate.compare(startingDate) == .OrderedAscending && currentDate.compare(endingDate) == . OrderedDescending {

//Here will your event code will come.

}